# @SequenceGenerator allocationSize 'duplicate key error' issue

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql, orm

I have a SequenceGenerator with an allocationSize of 5 (together with hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true). So from my understanding hibernate should try and return those values as new id:

1. - a) get the next value from the database sequence (e.g. id=70)
   - b) subtract the allocationSize (70-5=65)
   - c) return 65+1=66 as new id.
2. return 67 as new id.
3. return 68
4. return 69
5. return 70
6. latest sequence value hit, so proceed with 1a)

So the ids should range from 66 to 70. The problem in my case is that the generated ids are from 65 to 69. If I call next_value from within the database (postgres) and the sequence returns 65 i get a duplicate key error when hibernate generates 65 too afterwards (after getting 70 from the sequence).

Any clues or help on this topic?

€: Sorry, forgot to post my code:

Generator:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = GENERATOR_NAME)
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "hibernate_sequence", name = GENERATOR_NAME, allocationSize = 5)
private Integer id;
```

Sequence (Postgresql):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence
  INCREMENT 5
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 10041865
  CACHE 1;
```

Comment: always show your code..

Comment: How did you create the sequence in Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [pooled-lo optimizer](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-hidden-gem-the-pooled-lo-optimizer/) as it can inter-operate with other systems as well, or inserts issued from an administration console:

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator", strategy = "enhanced-sequence",
    parameters = {
        @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
            name = "optimizer", 
            value = "pooled"),
        @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
            name = "initial_value", 
            value = "1"),
        @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
            name = "increment_size", 
            value = "5")
    }
)
@GeneratedValue(
    strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
    generator = "sequenceGenerator")
private Long id;
```

Comment: The problem still exists. I generated ids from hibernate starting from 65 to 69 (next_value was 70). Then a database trigger used the id 75 (next_value was 75). When hibernate continued with the id generation (next_value = 80) it tried to use id 75 again.

Comment: There's a bug probably, because if the sequence was increased by a trigger, then Hibernate will always get the next low value from an unallocated value.

Comment: But isn't it the wrong behaviour if hibernate creates values from x-5 to x-1 instead of x-4 to x?

Comment: However, I just found out that it works with the "pooled-lo" optimizer. It was probably the "pooled"-bug you mentioned in your article. Thx for the hint!

Comment: They also got that fixed in the 5.0.0 branch. It should work from 5.x.x onwards.

Answer (score -3):

Change *hbm2ddl.auto* configuration, set it to `create` then it will work as the sequence value used for assigning the id in the table depends on the previous stored sequence number, not a bug.

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```